# How to check if all the elements of an array have subproperties in mocha-chai testing?

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to test a response from a server. Suppose the response is an array whose elements have a set of properties and the corresponding values are objects having other properties.

For example something like:

```
{
 "array": [
        {
            "porp1": {
                "subprop11": "a",
                "subprop12": [1,2]
            },
            "prop2": "c",
        },
        {
            "porp1": {
                "subprop11": "h",
                "subprop12": [3,2]
            },
            "prop2": "a",
        }
    ]
}
```

I want check all the elements of the arrays to have the properties and sub-properties. For the first level properties I managed to do that using `chai-things`:

```
const chai = require('chai');
chai.use(require('chai-things'));
....
res.body['array'].should.all.have.property('prop1');
res.body['array'].should.all.have.property("prop2");
```

How can I check the elements to have the subproperties `"subprop11"` and `"subprop12"?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to work

```
res.body['array'].should.all.have.nested.property('prop1.subprop11');
```